# Using The VM Module To Run Node.js Scripts: "ReferenceError: require is not a function"

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, require

I'm writing my own custom node.js server. It now handles static pages, AJAX GET, POST and OPTIONS requests (the latter for CORS), but I'm aware that the method I've chosen for running the server side GET and POST scripts is not optimal - the official node.js documentation states that launching numerous child node.js processes is a bad idea, as it's a resource hungry approach. It works, but I'm aware that there's probably a better method of achieving the same result.

So, I alighted upon the VM module. My first thought was that this would solve the problem of cluttering the machine with child processes, and make my server much more scalable.

There's one slight problem. My server side scripts, for tasks such as directory listing & sending the results back to the browser, begin with several **require** statements to load required modules.

Having finally written the code to read the script file, and pass it to vm.Script(), I now encounter an error:

"ReferenceError: require is not a function"

I've since learned that the reason for this, is that VM launches a bare V8 execution environment for the script, instead of an independent node.js execution environment. To make my idea work, I need VM to provide me with a separate, sandboxed node.js execution environment. How do I achieve this?

My preliminary researches tell me that I need to provide the VM execution environment with its own separate copy of the node.js globals, so that **require** functions as intended. Is my understanding as just provided correct? And if so, what steps do I need to take to perform this task?

Comment: Why do those scripts need to run inside a VM? Are they provided by third parties (so you need some sort of sandbox to run them in)?

Comment: They're my own scripts currently, but the intention is to make the web server safe for third party scripts as well. The sandboxing concept inherent in VM sounded like just the ticket when I first discovered it.

Plus, using the VM avoids spawning numerous node.js child processes, which, as I stated above, the official node,js documentation warns against as a bad idea for scalability and resource consumption.

Comment: In that case, take a look at [`vm2`](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2), which is like `vm`, but easier to control.

Comment: That looks good, but for one minor fly in the ointment. It requires node.js V6 or later. I'm interested in making my server compatible with earlier versions than V6.

Comment: In that case, search for [sandbox](https://npms.io/search?q=sandbox), there are alternatives :)

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to know how to achieve the result in my own code, instead of using something off the shelf. One, because I'll have complete control over the code, and two, the learning experience will be beneficial.

Answer (score 6):

> My preliminary researches tell me that I need to provide the VM execution environment with its own separate copy of the node.js globals, so that require functions as intended

That's correct for [`runInNewContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_options), which doesn't share the globals with the "parent" context (as opposed to [`runInThisContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_options)).

To provide the ability to `require` in your script, you can pass it as a function. The same goes for other locals, like `console`:

```
const vm = require('vm');

let sandbox = {
  require,
  console
};

vm.runInNewContext(`

let util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(util));

`, sandbox);
```

Instead of passing `require` directly, you can also pass a function that—say—implements module whitelisting (so you can control which modules the scripts are allowed to load).

Comment: The problem here is that `require` executes in the parent's global context rather than the global context set up by the VM module. This means that modules that are imported from your sandboxed module will no longer be sandboxed.

Comment: @BenBurns VM shouldn't be used to run unsafe code anyway, there are too many ways of breaking out, even without passing in functions like `require` :(

Comment: @robertklep I wasn't implying `vm` was a security sandbox. To put it differently, the issue with this approach is that modules imported by the script that is run by `vm` will not share a global context with the script that imported them. That a module would share a global context with its parent is often a critical design assumption for domain-specific scripting tools.